# What is this strongly scenting ground covering weed?

Tags: identification, weeds, ground-cover

Here is a weed I gathered the seeds from last year. It had bloomed on a Mediterranean island, Corsica, up in the mountains (around 2000 meters above see level, I believe snow covered 2-3 months pour year). I was so amazed by the strong scent of the plant that I hoped I could have it home somewhere.

Now I let it multiply in some pots of mine here, and am curious what indeed it is.

It head small opposite leaves (2-3mm), it gets kind of purple when it gets water deprived. Seedlings didn't bloom the first year. It is strong scented, about little like point, stronger and different. It could be some kind of microscopic sage, I'm curious...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Square stem? Labiatea/Laminaceae family. Member of such family are scented (basil, rosemary, thyme, sage, etc.), many species are also alpine.  I would go much more on thyme (or similar) than sage (inflorescence form), but ... I need to look my books.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi , basil indeed rings a bell. But the smell is far stronger and more "minty".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the scent and first image, I would say a Labiate/Laminaceae family member. But it is difficult from your photos. I have most problem with the second photo: the leaves are not very characteristic for known (by me) Laminaceae.

My best guess (from Kew's flora of Western Mediterranean) is *Mentha pulegium*, so it confirm your "minty" smell. The book say "strong smelling", and "pondsides".

This photo (about the habit and leave) could confirm it
http://tom-piergrossi.squarespace.com/buy-plants-m-r/mentha-pulegium .

Other mints have different inflorescence.

Answer (score 3):

From the images I could find, I confirm this is [**Mentha pulegium**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mentha_pulegium).

Be careful because it appears to contain a dangerous chemical. Not to be used in food or beverage, then.

Dangerous but Beautiful!

[image: Gardenology.org-IMG 2751 rbgs11jan.jpg]
By Raffi Kojian - http://Gardenology.org, [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), [Link](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=12734737)

Comment: Too bad its toxic... But I am with you and like your attempt to move it from corsica to your place.

Comment: @VividD, It's everywhere in the yard now. We'll see if it survives winter...